# Catching URLs processed by Firefox once clicking AJAX links

Tags: ajax, facebook

I was wondering if there is a simple way of "catching" the URLs processed by Firefox (or any browser for that matter) once I click them (e.g. click "Send friend request" on Facebook).

The "Friend Request" on Facebook is just an example, so please don't give me a specific link for that. I want to know if I can retrieve the URL that is being processed, e.g. http:// facebook.com / ajax / request.php?type=friend&id=1234567890
in a **simple** way - dissecting the code from source is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to write a GreaseMonkey script that attaches an event handler to each link on the page.

Once the link is clicked, you intercept it's it's `href` attribute and then it let it continue processing it's standard behavior.

Comment: Tom, that's a good idea, but I don't think it'll work in this specific situation. Facebook encodes a huge portion of their code. If you take a look at their source, you might see "ajaxify" come up a few times, and others like it. I've "translated" some of them into readable code, but not all of their links use the same method.
With their kind of encoding in place, no anchor tags are processed, but rather JS code that goes through a script that converts it into a real URL.
If I could pinpoint the anchor tag that is generated for each click, I wouldn't need what I described in my first post.

Comment: @Charles Gotcha - I see what you mean. Unfortunately, nothing comes to mind. Admittedly, I'm not sure what you're looking to do once you get the information but one trick might be to browse the site with JavaScript disabled just to see how it degrades. That may help give a clue as to what's happening in the usual rendering of the site. Only a guess though.